# How to filter and groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, filtering

I have a data set (made up the below as an example) and I am trying to group and filter at the same time. I want to groupby the occupation and then filter the Sex for just males. I am also working in pandas.

```
Occupation             Age    Sex
Accountant              23     Female
Doctor                  33     Male
Accountant              43     Male
Doctor                  28     Female
```

I'd like the final result to look something like this:

```
Occupation    Sex
Accountant     1
Doctor         1
```

So far I have come up with the below but it doesn't filter males for sex

```
data.groupby(['occupation'])[['sex']].count()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this panda??

Comment: It is. Just edited that in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `query` prior to `groupby`

```
data.query('Sex == "Male"').groupby('Occupation').Sex.size().reset_index()
```

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I missed up when inputting. Works now, thanks!